# Limit of the sine and logarithm function

Tags: limits, logarithms

How do I calculate the following?

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (-\ln(x) \sin(x)) $$

Comment: Please notice this difference: $\displaystyle lim_{x\to0^+} (-ln(x)sin(x))$ versus $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^+} (-\ln(x)\sin(x))$.  I edited accordingly.  The backslashes not only prevent italicization, they also provide proper spacing in things like $a\sin b$ and affect the position of the subscript $x\to0^+$, placing it directly under $\lim$ when that's in a displayed (as opposed to inline) context. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} (-\ln(x) \sin(x)) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \left(-x\ln(x) \cdot \frac{\sin x} x \right)
$$
This is equal to
$$
\left( \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} -x\ln(x) \right) \cdot \left( \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin x} x \right)
$$
provided those both exist.

The first of those can be found by writing $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\ln x}{1/x}$ and applying L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

Do you recognize this limit as having a certain indeterminate form?  Identify this form, and apply the standard technique from your textbook in order to deal with it.  In case you don't have a textbook, this is $0\cdot \infty$ type.  Rearrange the expression $\ln(x)\sin(x)$ to be $\frac{0}{0}$ form or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form.  Then use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: I am never clear why people are so addicted to L'Hopital's Rule. I find it easier just to put down the first few terms of the Taylor series when one is dealing with well-known functions ...

Comment: @almagest Both are valid methods, with rigorous underpinnings, so to each his own.

Comment: @almagest To paraphrase Terence Tao: Because when you first learn formally how to deal with such limits, students can't revert to power series. (If nothing else, it can lead to circular logic.) Later, yes, when they know how to formalize such an argument and are worried about the rigor of other things.

Comment: @almagest A plausible reason, I think, is that (usually?) L'Hopital appears earlier in calculus class, while Taylor appears quite later.

Comment: +1 incidentally. I always applaud attempts to make people think, rather than simply doing their homework for them!

Comment: @almagest: Also, $\ln(x)$ doesn't have a Taylor series (or even a Laurent series) about zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalents:*

$\sin x\sim_0 x$, hence $\;-\ln x\sin x\sim_0 -x\ln x$, and it is a basic limit with logarithms that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=0.$$
Furthermore, as $\ln x <0$ if $0<x<1$, we know $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}(-x\ln x)=0^+$.